# Adding Apex pages to lead layout page

Tags: apex, leads, google-map

I'm trying to add a Google Map to my lead page layout. I've made the page in Apex, how do I insert into my lead page layout? Alongside my custom fields, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Setup > Customize > Leads > Page Layouts`, edit `Lead layout`.

In the top box, you have an item `VisualForce pages`.

You can then drag and drop your page where you want in the page layout.